# How to run hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

https://github.com/arefin97/Medicine_Supply_Chain

Can anyone plzz tell me how to run this project based on hyperledger fabric. what are the steps and how to connect multiple computers for testing and how to run this because I'm getting too many errors.

Comment: Due to the specificity of the repository, you maybe should [open an issue](https://github.com/arefin97/Medicine_Supply_Chain/issues/new) on it stating you need a step-by-step and *detailing the errors you found*.

Comment: Ok I'll try that